# Intersection of a finite Galois extension with simple extensions

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, galois-theory

$f$ is an irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb Q[x]$, $Q \subset E$ is a finite Glaois extension. $\alpha, \beta$ are roots of $f$. Show that if $E$ is the $n$th cyclotomic field then $\mathbb Q(\alpha) \cap E = \mathbb Q (\beta)\cap E$.

First of all, note that $\alpha \in E$ iff $\beta \in E$ because Galois extension are normal. Then we can assume $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are both in $E$. If I can show that given $\sigma \in Aut_{\mathbb Q(\beta)}(E)$, $\sigma$ must fix $\alpha$, then I can show that they are equal by Galois correspondence, but that is not obvious.

Comment: $E/Q$ is abelian thus $(Q(a)\cap E)/Q$ is Galois. Let $\sigma \in Aut(\overline{Q}/Q)$ such that $\sigma(a)=b$

Comment: How does that lead to the conclusion?

Comment: $\sigma( Q(a)\cap E) = ?$

Comment: Are you showing that there is an automorphism between them rather than that they are equal?

Comment: Yes and no. ${}{}{}$

Comment: Sorry I am so confused, can you maybe provide me with more details. I know that they are supposed to be Galois but I failed to see how I should take advantage of it.

Comment: $\sigma( Q(a)\cap E) = ?$

Comment: $\sigma$ would take $\alpha \to \beta$, but it is not clear how it should act on $E$.

Comment: Well $E = Q(\zeta_n)$ where $\zeta_n = e^{2i \pi /n}$, not many possible choices for $\sigma|_E$

Comment: Now I get it. $Q(\alpha)$ being Galois means that $f$ must split in it, so it must contain $\beta$ as well.

Comment: Not at all. $Q(a)/Q$ is not Galois, who said that ? Where you are stuck is to see how $\sigma$ acts on $\zeta_n$.

Comment: I am assuming $\alpha$ is in $E$

Comment: Ok but $a$ is not in $E$ (try with $a = 5^{1/4} e^{2i \pi / 16}, E = \Bbb{Q}(i)$)

Comment: Yeah I divided it into two cases. Anyway, sorry to drag you into such a long conversation.

Answer (score 1):

$E/\Bbb{Q}$  is abelian (*) thus $(\Bbb{Q}(a)\cap E)/\Bbb{Q}$ is Galois. Let $\sigma \in Aut(\overline{\Bbb{Q}}/\Bbb{Q})$ such that $\sigma(a)=b $.

$E/\Bbb{Q}$ is Galois thus $\sigma(E) = E$. And $\sigma(\Bbb{Q}(a)) = \sigma(\Bbb{Q})(\sigma(a)) = \Bbb{Q}(b)$. Thus $\sigma(\Bbb{Q}(a)\cap E) = \sigma(\Bbb{Q}(a)) \cap \sigma(E) = \Bbb{Q}(b) \cap E$.

On the other hand $(\Bbb{Q}(a)\cap E)/\Bbb{Q}$ is Galois thus $\sigma(\Bbb{Q}(a)\cap E) =\Bbb{Q}(a)\cap E$.

---

(*) $E = \Bbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$ where $\zeta_n = e^{2i \pi /n}$. As $\zeta_n$ is a root of $X^n-1$ and $E$ contains all the roots of $X^n-1$ then $E/ \Bbb{Q}$ is Galois.

Any $\rho \in Aut(E/\Bbb{Q})$ must send $\zeta_n$ to another root of $X^n-1$ thus to some $\zeta_n^{m_\rho}$ (with $gcd(n,m_\rho)=1$) so $\rho$ sends $\zeta_n^a$ to $\zeta_n^{am_\rho}$ and $\rho \mapsto  m_\rho$ is an embedding $Aut(E/\Bbb{Q} ) \to \Bbb{Z/n Z}^\times$. Whence $Aut(E/\Bbb{Q} )$ is abelian.

For any subfield $K \subset E$ with $H = Aut(E/K)$ we'll have that $K = E^H$ (the subfield fixed by $H$) and $\rho(K) = E^{\rho H \rho^{-1}} = E^H = K$ implies $K/\Bbb{Q}$ is Galois (with $Aut(K/\Bbb{Q}) = Aut(E/\Bbb{Q})/H$ abelian).